# iMacros: How can i make a random choice click?

Tags: imacros

How can I set random choice for 'click' or 'don't click'?

In this example I need let iMacros make random choice of one of this 3 lines.

```
TAG POS=57 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio<SP>exportOuterCircle
TAG POS=58 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio<SP>exportOuterCircle
TAG POS=59 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio<SP>exportOuterCircle
```

I new in this =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work in .iim, I made separate variables to set the range.

But I recommend using javascript (EVAL execute javascript code) and save the iMacros script in .js format

```
SET !VAR1 57
SET !VAR2 59
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*({{!VAR2}}-{{!VAR1}}) + {{!VAR1}}); randomNumber;")
TAG POS={{!VAR3}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio<SP>exportOuterCircle
```